# I am having performance issues with rendering 1 million triangles using OpenGL

Tags: c++, performance, opengl, nvidia, gpu-instancing

I am using an RTX 3060 GPU (laptop version) and I am trying to render 1 million triangles(via instancing of 500,000 instanced quads) and the GPU seems to be taking around 40ms as shown in nsight and the CPU is practically doing nothing. My shaders are simple vertex and fragment shaders with nothing else in them. This seems very trivial as I thought GPUs could render millions of triangles easily. the main render loop looks like this:

```
m_RenderData.InitialColorPass->Use();
m_RenderData.InitialColorPass->SetUniformMat4("ViewProjection", ViewProjectionMatrix);

InstanceBatch.BeginInstanceBatch();

glDrawElementsInstanced(
    GL_TRIANGLES,                     
    (GLuint)(Instance.GetCount()),     
    GL_UNSIGNED_INT,                   
    nullptr,                          
    (GLuint)(InstanceBatch.GetNumberOfInstances())
);

InstanceBatch.EndInstanceBatch();
```

Within begin instance batch I unmap the buffer containing matrix data

```
if (m_CurrentBufferIndex == 0)
    m_InstanceBuffer.UnMap();
else if (m_CurrentBufferIndex == 1)
    m_InstanceSecondBuffer.UnMap();
else
    m_InstanceThirdBuffer.UnMap();

m_InstanceVAO.Bind();
```

and then in end instance batch i simply remap the buffer range, i do this with asynchronous flags enabled and triple buffering.

```
if (m_CurrentBufferIndex == 0)
{
    m_BufferMapBase = (float*)m_InstanceSecondBuffer.MapBufferRange();
    m_InstanceVAO.AttachVertexBuffer(m_InstanceSecondBuffer, 1, m_AttributeDataCopy.Offsets[1], m_AttributeDataCopy.Strides[1]);
    m_CurrentBufferIndex = 1;
}
else if (m_CurrentBufferIndex == 1)
{
    m_BufferMapBase = (float*)m_InstanceThirdBuffer.MapBufferRange();
    m_InstanceVAO.AttachVertexBuffer(m_InstanceThirdBuffer, 1, m_AttributeDataCopy.Offsets[1], m_AttributeDataCopy.Strides[1]);
    m_CurrentBufferIndex = 2;
}
else
{
    m_BufferMapBase = (float*)m_InstanceBuffer.MapBufferRange();
    m_InstanceVAO.AttachVertexBuffer(m_InstanceBuffer, 1, m_AttributeDataCopy.Offsets[1], m_AttributeDataCopy.Strides[1]);
    m_CurrentBufferIndex = 0;
}
```

At first I figured it was a synchronising issue with the buffers and waiting on the gpu which is why I implemented triple buffering, whilst this reduced the cpu time practically down to nothing (around 2ms per frame) the GPU was still taking a long time. I am starting to think this is maybe hardware limitation but a 3060 even on a laptop is a powerful GPU. Next I thought vsync was enabled and disabled that within the control panel and that seemed to do nothing. My integrated graphics (amd ryzen 7 5800) also slightly outperforms my dedicated 3060.

one warning I started to get recently was
[Core-Warn] Pixel-path performance warning: Pixel transfer is synchronized with 3D rendering.
and this occurs once when I initially remap the buffer or reconstruct the buffer with a new size.

Comment: How large are your triangles? How much overdraw do you produce? Is the vertex processing or the fragment processing the bottleneck? A gpu might be able to render a million tiny triangles, but it very likely isn't able to render a million triangles where each of them covers the whole screen.

Comment: the quads are 1x1, I never thought that the size of the triangles would affect performance or anything like overdraw i don't know how i missed that, i am going to run some tests with smaller triangles then reply back.

Comment: i resized the triangles to a really tiny space and i still get the same performance. As for vertex or fragment processing i wouldn't think any of them would not be performant, all that happens in the fragment shader is it sets a color and in the vertex the Position it multiplied by the view projection matrix.

Comment: @TooGood Any question concerning the speed of a C++ program must be accompanied by the build settings used when building the application.  The most important of these settings are the *optimization* flags used.  If you are running an unoptimized or "debug" build, then the timings you are reporting are meaningless.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The C++ program is in release, i have already confirmed the CPU is not the issue with clockl timers and Nvidia nsight, the CPU takes around 1 - 1.5ms per frame whilst the  GPU is taking 40ms per frame.  99% of the GPU time is coming from the glDrawInstanced call on the GPU side according to nsight. EDIT: i also wanted to add some more build settings:
Favor fast code (/Ot)
(/Oi)
Any Suitable (/Ob2)
these basically just enable intrinsic functions and i have also tested with different instruction sets and I am current using
Streaming SIMD Extensions 2

Comment: @TooGood: "*instanced quads*" Please don't use instancing for quads.

Comment: @NicolBolas This is obviously just for testing purposes, I want to build this renderer up more and include 3D detailed models but I need to address performance issues first and I needed a way to quickly benchmark the core method for rendering which it all come down to is just triangles.

Comment: Just a simple test to know approximately (under-approximation) the number of triangle that can be drawn on you machine : install blender, open the default cube scene, then triangularize it, then subdivide the cube so there are up to a million triangles, print the statistics. It took less ~10 minutes on my machine and I did not used Blender since 10 years. On a Nvidia 1660S, it can draw 6M triangle at 30-40 FPS (with no overdraw in my case since I removed the back faces). Your GPU should be able to do better than that. Note Blender use OpenGL and all triangles are drawn in my case.

Comment: @JérômeRichard right this should identify whether my program is at fault I will install it and will put the results here

Comment: @JérômeRichard at 7 million triangles with a cube subdivided my dedicated graphics gets 30FPS. EDIT: i did some more testing and it seems that on blender the GPU maxes out at 90-95% whilst on my program it only maxes out at 40%. with the CPU being at 15% (most of that is from other programs).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the problem, turns out one of the mapped buffers was incorrectly attached to a vertex array, so I was only using double buffering not triple as I intended because every frame there would be no mapping so the draw call would be drawing from an empty buffer. Looking back at it now it seems obvious with a high GPU usage and low CPU with that much data.
EDIT: i also had some extra timers i forgot to remove and that was affecting it aswell although i dont know why it wasn't showing up in CPU usage.